# Get srcset of an image of a wordpress post with parse_blocks and render_block

Tags: wordpress, srcset

I'm using the parse_block() and the render_block() method to split the_content() and reinject content in my custom page template.
All works fine until I test the website on a mobile. None of images are shown. The reason is that the srcset is not included in the render_block().

Here is how I'm currently working :

```
<?php
$post = get_post(); 
$blocksHeading = array();
$blocksParagraph = array();
$blocksHTML = array();
$blocksImage = array();

if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
    $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
    foreach($blocks as $block){
        // print_r($block);
        if( 'core/heading' === $block['blockName']){
            // echo render_block($block);
            $blocksHeading[] = $block;
        }
        if( 'core/html' === $block['blockName']){
            // echo render_block($block);
            $blocksHTML[] = $block;
        }
        if( 'core/image' === $block['blockName']){
            // echo render_block($block);
            $blocksImage[] = $block;
        }
        if( 'core/paragraph' === $block['blockName']){
            // echo render_block($block);
            $blocksParagraph[] = $block;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my page template…

```
echo render_block($blocksImage[0]);
```

So the output looks like this :

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img src="http://my-site/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/IMG_1586.png" alt="" class="wp-image-53"/></figure>
```

There is thus no srcset :(

Can someone help me ?